# The least possible value of $\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|$ if $|z|\geq 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Find the least possible value of $$\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|$$ if $|z|\geq 3.$

The answer given is $\large\frac{8}{3},$ which can be obtained by using triangle inequality. But this would be so only if $|z|$ has the fixed value $3.$ Will the least value be same if $|z|$ takes a value bigger than $3?$

Is the question correct?

Comment: As you said, this can be solved with the triangle inequality: $\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right| \ge |z| - \frac{1}{|z|} \ge 3- \frac 13 = \frac 83$ for $|z| \ge 3$, with equality for $z=3$. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: The triangle inequality gives you a lower bound for $|z+\frac 1z|$, i.e. the minimum must be $\ge \frac 83$. If you present at least one point for which the equality is attained, you prove that the minimum is actually $\frac 83$

Comment: *Correction:* Equality holds for $z=\pm 3i$, not for $z=3$.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is the question correct"? Do you ask whether the **answer** $8/3$ is correct?

Comment: I meant that won't the minimum change as $|z|$ increases . But I think I got confused between minimum and maximum

Comment: It is true that for each value of $|z|$, there is a different minimum (and maximum) value for your expression. But we don't really have to worry about that. All we care about is the smallest of these minima, not which minimum corresponds to any particular $|z|$.

Comment: @Maverick For different values of $|z|$ ,  only the value of expression $\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|$ changes , not the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Answer, for ease of reading, $$g(z):=\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|.$$

> > Find the least possible value of $$\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|$$ if $|z|\geq 3.$
>
> The answer given is $\large\frac{8}{3}$

In other words, the book is (correctly) claiming that $$\forall z{\in}\mathbb C \;\left(|z|\geq3\implies g(z)\geq\frac83\right),$$ i.e., every complex number that is $3$ or more units from the origin satisfies $g(z)\geq\frac83.$

> But this would be so **only if** $|z|$ has the fixed value $3.$

On the other hand, you are (falsely) claiming that $$\forall z{\in}\mathbb C \;\left(g(z)\geq\frac83\implies|z|=3\right),$$  i.e., every complex number that satisfies $g(z)\geq\frac83$ is $3$ units from the origin.

> Will the least value be same if $|z|$ takes a value bigger than $3?$

To be clear, when speaking of the “least value” of $f(z),$ we are considering $f(z)$'s values as $z$ varies over *some* **domain of interest** (typically $f$'s domain—but occasionally some subset of this domain). So:

- As $z$ varies over $|z|\geq3,$ the least value of $g(z)$ is
  $\frac83.\quad\leftarrow$ the book's answer
- As $z$ varies over $|z|\geq17,$ the least value of $g(z)$ is $k.$
  $(k$ is yet to be determined, but we at least know that it is at least $\frac83.)$